# Autoupdate Chrome Extension only works on one computer

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I'm hosting the xml and crx on a server of mine, but it seems like updates (pressing the "Update" button on chrome://extensions) only work on the computer I built and transferred the files from. I have my URLs and files configured properly, I think, because autoupdate works perfect my own machine. Can you shed any light on how to make it the same for others?

Comment: "I have my URLs and files configured properly, I think," - Confirm that. Open the pertinent URLs in a browser on the other machine and make sure you get the expected result.

Comment: Make sure to look through the "Related" questions listed to the right. There might be some tidbit in there that will help.